# lsof shell command in php denied

Tags: php, awk, server, lsof

i have the following code:

```
        $cmd="lsof | awk '{print $1 \" \" $2 \" \" $3 \" \" $9}'";
        $info = shell_exec($cmd);        
        $processors = preg_split('/\s?\n\s?\n/', trim($info));
        $processors = explode("\n",$processors[0]);
        foreach($processors as $processor){
           echo $processor."\n";
        }
```

when i run it on the command line i get positive results. however, when i run it on a php script i get:

`systemd 1 root denied)` for each `$processor`

Comment: IMHO not sure `awk` tag should be there for this post or not, may be `bash` tag since `lsof` is a shell command(internal or external)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I given a try to your code posted, I too got the same errors(was able to re-produce the errors).

Then I tried to put only `lsof` in place of your complete `lsof` command with `awk` to see whats the complete error and I got following error.

```
COMMAND PID    USER   FD      TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
sh        1    root  cwd   unknown                            /proc/1/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
sh        1    root  rtd   unknown                            /proc/1/root (readlink: Permission denied)
sh        1    root  txt   unknown                            /proc/1/exe (readlink: Permission denied)
sh        1    root NOFD                                      /proc/1/fd (opendir: Permission denied)
time      9    root  cwd   unknown                            /proc/9/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
time      9    root  rtd   unknown                            /proc/9/root (readlink: Permission denied)
```

After that I googled and found a great link https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109228 (cross site reference) which tells us that `lsof` is providing error since we don't have access on those files/commands and obviously we are NOT running command with `root`.

So to overcome this problem IMHO you could:

- Run `lsof` command as `sudo` to get rid of errors, in case your user has sudo access to run this command.
- In case you are NOT interested in root processes details then you could remove these errors by sending them to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the full output of `lsof` you'll see most lines look like:

```
COMMAND     PID   TID TASKCMD            USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
systemd       1                          root  cwd   unknown                                         /proc/1/cwd (readlink: Permission denied)
```

Because the user you're running as doesn't have permissions to look at processes that aren't its own.

Try: `sudo lsof`